# Postfix connects to wrong relay?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, unix, smtp, ubuntu-10.10

I am trying to set up postfix on my ubuntu server in order to send emails via my isp's smtp server. I seem to have missed something because the mail.log tells me:

```
Jan 19 11:23:11 mediaserver postfix/smtp[5722]: CD73EA05B7: to=<xxxx.xxxxxx@gmx.de>, relay=new.mailia.net[85.183.240.20]:25, delay=6.2, delays=5.7/0.02/0.5/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; server new.mailia.net[85.183.240.20] said: 535 5.7.0 Error: authentication failed: )
```

The relay "new.mailia.net[85.183.240.20]:25" was not set up by me. I use "relayhost = smtp.alice.de". Why is postfix trying to connect to a different server?

Here is my main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mediaserver
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = mediaserver, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = smtp.alice.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
inet_protocols = all
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Output of postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mediaserver, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
myhostname = mediaserver
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter =
relayhost = smtp.alice.de
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Please provide the output from `postconf -n`

Comment: Try `grep -ir "new.mailia.net" /etc/`

Comment: added the postconf -n output

Comment: grep -ir "new.mailia.net" /etc/ did not print any results...

Answer (score 1):

Check for a file called "transport" in your postfix config directory (usually /etc/postfix).  That is a standard location to configure smarthosts and that might be your issue.

The smarthost/relay might be configured by IP address, I'd do another "grep -r XXX" for that IP and host in your postfix config directory.

Comment: Apparently the URL "new.mailia.net" is a forward. I tried to use another provider, which worked correctly...

Comment: I was not able to find a transport file. The relayhost ist stored in the main.cf.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the actual authentication. Maybe my authentication method is not allowed...